# How can I set an Q_ENUM from a QString

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set a Q_ENUM from a QString but I've got no idea how to do this. Anyone with experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to get the matching QMetaEnum out of the QMetaObject for the QObject based type that Q_ENUM is declared in. Once you have that, you can get the integer that the string represents. For an example class MyEnumContainer with an enum called EnumName, which has an entry called SomeKeyInEnumName, this might look something like the following:

```
QMetaObject* metaObject = MyEnumContainer::staticMetaObject();
int enumIndex = metaObject->indexOfEnumerator("EnumName");
QMetaEnum enum = metaObject->enumerator(enumIndex);
int enumValue = enum.keyToValue("SomeKeyInEnumName");
```

For other useful tricks in QMetaEnum, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html should give you some ideas.

Comment: It seems the question is about setting enum keys rather than getting enum values. But then again, it could also be poorly worded.

Comment: staticMetaObject() does not exist any longer

Answer (score 5):

Example of an enum (works also for normal enum):

```
enum class MyEnumType
{
   foo,
   bar
};
Q_ENUM(MyEnumType)
```

Easiest way I found is like this, using 2 essential lines:

```
auto&& metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<MyEnumType>();
MyEnumType wantedEnum = static_cast<MyEnumType>(metaEnum.keyToValue("foo")));
```

Just be careful to only execute `keyToValue` when the string is not empty, using `!yourString.isEmpty()`. In my case, the enum value ended up being `0xFF` in memory. I didn't include this in the code snippet because this check depends on your implementation.

Comment: `QMetaEnum::keyToValue` takes `char *` as parameter, you're passing `QString`. This won't even compile.

Comment: Won’t, or you haven’t tried it? It converts it implicitly. That worked for me, let me know if this doesn’t for you.

Comment: If it works for you then for sure we're using different compilers or compiler options. Probably that's the explanation.

Comment: I think metaEnum.keyToValue result should be checked. If "foo" is not in the enum list you will get -1 as result.